# Improve query performance for joined tables with related date ranges

Tags: sql, database, performance

## Info

---

I need some help in figuring out the best way to query a set of tables. The need is to find the minimum and maximum months for which data is available from two interconnected tables. The tables and columns in question are described below:

Stocks

```
stock_id | region_id
```

Regions

```
region_id | region_name
```

StockReturns

```
stock_id | month | return
```

RegionReturns

```
region_id | return_type_id | month | return
```

ReturnType

```
return_type_id | return_type_name
```

## Question

---

**I've created a sandbox for this at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce2eee/1)**

The question I'm looking to answer is: **For a given start and end months (190001, 201310), what are the earliest and latest returns data available for both a stock (VTI) and its corresponding region (1)?** This data will then be used to further query other tables with the correct start and end months based on the date range.

My current query (described below) is starting to creep up in terms of execution time and as this is the primary query that will run on most webpage loads, I'm concerned about performance.

About the data, the schema isn't set in stone and can be changed if there's a better fit for these types of queries. Also, ReturnType is built like EAV currently but it has a finite limit of options (5 in the production table). The StockReturns table currently has over 100,000 rows and will have an upper-bound of 2 million records. The RegionReturns table has 3000 rows with an upper-bound of 5000.

Currently I'm querying with something like:

```
SELECT s.stock_id
    ,MIN(sr.month) AS start_month
    ,MAX(sr.month) AS end_month
FROM StockReturns sr
INNER JOIN Stocks s ON sr.stock_id = s.stock_id AND s.stock_id = 'VTI'
INNER JOIN Regions r ON s.region_id = r.region_id
INNER JOIN RegionReturns rf  ON s.region_id = rf.region_id
  AND rf.return_type_id = 1
  AND sr.month = rf.month
INNER JOIN RegionReturns mkt ON s.region_id = mkt.region_id
  AND mkt.return_type_id = 2
  AND sr.month = mkt.month
WHERE sr.month BETWEEN 190001 AND 201310
GROUP BY s.stock_id
```

The answer in this case should be:

```
stock_id | start_month | end_month
--------- ------------- ----------
VTI      | 201301      | 201302
```

Comment: The query looks ok. Are you running on proper hardware? Even with 2 million rows your query should return in a few seconds with proper indexing. I would focus on indexes as it seems to be your bottle neck.

Comment: Please post the execution plan so we can take a look at what you have. Also what database are you using?

Comment: I'm using sqlite to develop and benchmark. I created various indexes to support the query and prepared a sample database with 1,000,000 rows.The query timer reports CPU time of `user 8.751938 sys 0.546234` when using my query. This is far too long for this use. I ran the query in the way described below and it runs with CPU time `user 0.010647 sys 0.000222`. Any thoughts on why that may be?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the join with the Regions table, as you would only join to that table if you needed the region name. Since you're just checking to see if both return types exist for the stock's region, you can also use an exist clause.

How about trying this out?

```
SELECT sr.stock_id, 
       MIN(sr.month) AS start_month, 
       MAX(sr.month) AS end_month

FROM   StockReturns sr,
       Stocks s

WHERE  sr.stock_id = s.stock_id
AND    s.stock_id = 'VTI'
AND    sr.month BETWEEN 190001 AND 201310
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   RegionReturns rr
               WHERE  rr.region_id = s.region_id
               AND    rr.return_type_id = 1
               AND    rr.month = sr.month)
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   RegionReturns rr
               WHERE  rr.region_id = s.region_id
               AND    rr.return_type_id = 2
               AND    rr.month = sr.month)

GROUP BY sr.stock_id
```

Comment: Just tried this out on a sample database described above and it runs  super fast. Any thoughts on why that may be? As far as the join, I need it as this feeds into an ORM and the can only Hydrate via the Region table.